# X-Axis Lines(Strokes) are not visible in the Highcharts Linecharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

X-Axis Lines(Strokes) are not visisble in the linecharts highchart..how to get it ..the chart looks like this..can any one help.

[image]

Comment: It should be visible defaulty, could you supply live demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gridLineWidth=1, along with y-axis properties..
```